# Interpolation Search in

Tags: c

Hello i try to implement interpolation search. But for some reason it does not work with the last element of a integer array.

```
int interPolSearch(int arr[], int n, int k, int criticalCounter) 




while (arr[r] != arr[l] && k >= arr[l] && k <= arr[r])                                  //while the lowest index is smaller or equal to the upper bound
{
    m = l + ((r - l) / (arr[r] - arr[l])) * (k - arr[l]);                               //start the search with this formula

    if (k == arr[m])                                                                    //if the key was found in the array then return the index value
    {
        criticalCounter++;
        printf("The index of the key is: %d\n", m);
        printf("Interpolation search performed the critical operation: %d times\n", criticalCounter);
        return m;
    }

    else if (k < arr[m])
    {
        r = m - 1;                                                                      //if the key is smaller than m split the array again
        criticalCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
        (l = m + 1);                                                                    //if the key is bigger go through the upper half of the array
        criticalCounter++;
    }
}

printf("The value was not found\n");
return -1;                                          //if the key is not found return -1
```

}

In my implementation in the main function it looks like this

```
void genSortArr(int arr[], int n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arr[i] = i + 1;
}
}

#define MAX_INPUT 100000
int main()
{
int mid, key;
int arr[MAX_INPUT];
scanf("%d", &len);
genSortArr(arr, len)
mid = (len - 1);
key = Arr[mid];
interPolSearch(Arr, len, key, criticalCounter);
}
```

For some reason it cannot find the search value. (Where the key is the last value of the array, len the length of the array.)

Comment: Please show enough code to compile and reproduce. What is `Arr`? What is `len`? Where and how are they defined? Please copy&paste the reduced code to avoid compilation errors resulting from missing brackets etc.

Comment: You should run your code in a debugger. As your elements are incremented by 1 only, your calcilation might not yield the desired result. As you are doing integer arithmetics when calculating your new `m` maybe you never get there due to rounding. Step through the code and watch how your index variables change.